# Why is there a small circle on my html5 select box, android?

Tags: android, css, html

A small circle appears on my select box, option of the menu and I can't figure out why... Same for all browsers.

Hope you can help.[image: Annoying circle on right of the menu.]
Thanks

Comment: it may be because of the radio button applied to it with attribute checked... post some codes here to get a better idea..

Comment: It is called a Radio button in Android. developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html
 Show some code to help us figure out what you did wrong.